# Hadoop delete all files ends with a name in a folder

Tags: hadoop, cmd

How can I delete all files end with a specific name on HDFS? I'm trying to type `hadoop fs -rm -R /path/*<end_of_file_name>`, where * is passed as a wildcard. But I received an error not able to find such file or directory.

Comment: You have used the [[tag:cmd]] tag. Does that mean you have installed hadoop on a Windows system? If so, are you using WSL, (please add the [[tag:windows]] and [[tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux]]/[[tag:wsl-2]] tags); if not please remove the [[tag:cmd]] tag. You have a considerably better chance of receiving assistance if your question targets the appropriate audiences. Please also add a little more detail, so that we understand exactly how you got to the position you are currently in, so that we can replicate or understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk is expanded within your local shell; you need to quote the argument so that the full string is passed to the namenode

```
hadoop fs -rm "/path/*end"
```